# Draw line between two subplots

Tags: matlab

I have two two-by-n arrays, representing 2d-points. These two arrays are plotted in the same figure, but in two different subplots. For every point in one of the arrays, there is a corresponding point i the other array. I want to show this correspondance by drawing a line from one of the subplots to the other subplot.

The solutions i have found are something like:

```
 ah=axes('position',[.2,.2,.6,.6],'visible','off'); % <- select your pos...
 line([.1,.9],[.1,.9],'parent',ah,'linewidth',5);
```

This plots a line in the coordinate system given by the axes call. In order for this to work for me i need a way to change coordinate system between the subplots system and the new system. Anybody know how this can be done?

Maybe there is different way of doing this. If so i would love to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you have to convert axes coordinates to figure coordinates. Then you can use [ANNOTATION](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/annotation.html) function to draw lines in the figure.

You can use [Data space to figure units conversion (ds2nfu)](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10656-data-space-to-figure-units-conversion) submission on FileExchange.

Here is a code example:

```
% two 2x5 arrays with random data
a1 = rand(2,5);
a2 = rand(2,5);

% two subplots
subplot(211)
scatter(a1(1,:),a1(2,:))
% Convert axes coordinates to figure coordinates for 1st axes
[xa1 ya1] = ds2nfu(a1(1,:),a1(2,:));


subplot(212)
scatter(a2(1,:),a2(2,:))
% Convert axes coordinates to figure coordinates for 2nd axes
[xa2 ya2] = ds2nfu(a2(1,:),a2(2,:));

% draw the lines
for k=1:numel(xa1)
    annotation('line',[xa1(k) xa2(k)],[ya1(k) ya2(k)],'color','r');
end
```

Make sure your data arrays are equal in size.

**Edit:** The code above will do data conversion for a current axes. You can also do it for particular axes:

```
hAx1 = subplot(211);
% ...
[xa1 ya1] = ds2nfu(hAx1, a1(1,:),a1(2,:));
```

Comment: Does not work for me: the lines are drawn from one `subplot` to the other, but they do not link the points. Moreover, when I resize the figure, the lines change their relative positions...

Comment: I think it's the bug in the submitted script. @Shai

Comment: Just noticed @Shai comment. It might be necessary to set proper units for the figure before applying ds2nfu.

Comment: Interestingly, the code above works only if I don't set the Units property for the figure at all. If I set it even to the default one (pixels) the lines do not line up with the points. Strange...

Answer (score -2):

A simple solution is to use the toolbar in the figure window. Just click "insert" and then "Line".