# How to avoid grid showing in between subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have seen on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52095337/plotting-grids-across-the-subplots-python-matplotlib) that some people where asking how to have the grid lines showing in between subplots.

However in `matplotlib 2.1.1` I have this as default behavior - and I actually don't want it.

```
n_cols   = 2 # or 1
fig,axes = plt.subplots(3, n_cols, sharex='all', sharey='row')
axes     = axes.reshape((3,n_cols));

for input in inputs:
    ax1 = axes[0,column[input]].plot(...)
    ax1.yaxis.grid(True)
    ax1.xaxis.grid(True)
    ax2 = axes[1,column[input]].plot(...)
    ax2.yaxis.grid(True)
    ax2.xaxis.grid(True)
    ax3 = axes[2,column[input]].plot(...)
    ax3.yaxis.grid(True)
    ax3.xaxis.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

So yes,  the grid is set multiple times to `True` for each axis.

[image]

Comment: What you see as "connecting lines" between the subplots are not the gridlines but the ticks. You see that they are black, while the grid is grey. To remove ticks see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998430/remove-xticks-in-a-matplotlib-plot

Comment: Ooooh, great thanks! Haha..